# Show that the random variable $V=X-a$ and $U=a-X$ have same distribution?

Tags: self-study, moments, cumulative-distribution-function

Given $X$ is a continuous random variable whose density is symmetric about a point $a$.

Show that $V=X-a$ and $U=a-X$ have same distribution.

---

$$F_U(u) = P(U \leq u) = P(X-a \leq u) = F_X(a+u)$$   and similarly $$F_W(w) = 1 - F_X(a-w)  \longrightarrow f_U(w) = f_X(a+w) = f_X(a-w)$$ by symmetry. Therefore,  $f_U(u) = f_X(a+u)$  by changing variable $w$ to $u$, which shows $f_U(u)=f_W(u)$.  Is this solution right? Thanks!

Comment: Can you solve the problem for the special case $a=0$?

Comment: user30438, please emulate the markup in the first half of your question to make the second half readable.

Comment: I have typeset the second half of your post to enhance readability. Please check that I haven't inadvertently changed the meaning of anything.

Comment: You can do this directly from the definition of the distribution function and using the given symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It is sufficient to show that $U$ and $V$ have the same cumulative distribution function. To see that, notice that $\mathbb P(a-X\leqslant t)=\mathbb P(a-t\leqslant X)=\int_{a-t}^\infty f_X(s)\mathrm ds$, then use a substitution. (notice that $\mathbb P\{a-t=X\}=0$ since $X$ has a density)
- Express the $(2p+1)$-th moment in terms of an integral involving $f_X$, then use a substitution.

Comment: You're right (+1), but why go through the integration when you really need only to invoke basic properties of inequalities? To wit, the events $V\le t$, $X-a\le t$, and $X\le a+t$ are identical (these are just equivalent descriptions of the same set); $\Pr(X\le a+t) = \Pr(X\ge a-t)$ is what it means for $X$ to be symmetric about $a$; and the events $X\ge a-t$, $-X\le t-a$, $a-X\le t$, and $U\le t$ are identical. Consequently $F_V(t)=F_U(t)$ for all numbers $t$, meaning $V$ and $U$ have the same distribution. The continuity assumption was not needed anywhere.

Comment: The assumption is on the density. The approach you suggest will work, but we need to justify $P(X\leqslant a+t)=P(X\geqslant a-t)$.

Comment: That is the *assumption*: it is what it means to be symmetric about $a$. This way of expressing symmetry is fully general, because it applies to all distributions, not just those that have densities.

Comment: @whuber: I think Davide is trying to draw out a subtle point about the wording of the question. If it had been stated "Let $X$ be a *symmetric* random variable with density $f$..." there would be little doubt. The question instead simply states that "$X$ is a continuous random variable with *symmetric* density $f$..." That leaves something to be proved. Whether that was the *intent* of the question is another matter altogether. (The slight distinction may well have been lost on the one originally posing it!)

Comment: @whuber Pr(X≤a+t)=Pr(X≥a−t) , can you explain it a bit more. I understand that pdf is symmetric; but Pr(X≤a+t) represents cdf.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you for that comment. Although I was aware of that distinction, what I am trying to convey here is the idea that a demonstration (or better, proof) is an opportunity to provide insight. One way to do that is to eschew sophisticated constructions in favor of more basic arguments. The idea in the present case is that relying on a density and applying the substitution rule of integration somewhat obscure a simple, intuitive phenomenon: the two variables in question are equidistributed because the symmetry guarantees the sets $\{V\le t\}$ and $\{U\le t\}$ are always equiprobable.

Comment: user30438 Perhaps the best way to see that $\Pr(X\le a+t)=\Pr(X\ge a-t)$ is to draw graphs of both functions (of $t$). A more formal way is to differentiate both sides with respect to $t$: the derivatives are the values of the PDF at $a\pm t$ which, by assumption, are equal. Since both probabilities have the same limiting value of $0$ as $t\to -\infty$ and their derivatives agree, they must be the same function. I think the most useful part of this exercise may be in seeing how complicated problems about distributions sometimes become simple when re-expressed in terms of CDFs.

Comment: @whuber: I know what you are driving at and agree with the general point, though at the moment, I still think an invocation of calculus is unavoidable to properly tie up all the loose ends. If our point of departure is simply that $X$ is symmetric about $a$, meaning $X - a \stackrel{d}{=} a - X$, then there is nothing really to prove in the first part. If instead our point of departure is only that $X$ has symmetric density $f$, then we still need to show $$\text{symmetric }\, f \implies X\, \text{ symmetric}\,.$$ This piece seems to require getting our hands dirty. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) From a didactic perspective, I believe there is considerable merit to your suggestion of first treating a general symmetric $X$ case and *then* showing how the assumption given in the problem implies said symmetry. (I realize my pedantry is showing.)

Comment: @Cardinal I agree that *some* mechanism to relate a density to probability is needed. But historically such things could be done long before Calculus was invented, so perhaps a simple intuitive demonstration is still possible. Were we to draw the graph of the density $f$ and note its mirror symmetry around $x=a$, then would it not be immediate that the region to the left of $a+t$ is *congruent* to the region to the right of $a-t$? From that, the formula for the symmetry of the CDF follows easily. (Technically, we only need invariance of Lebesgue measure under reflections in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @whuber: Yes, certainly. I think we're on the same page. :-) (+1)

Comment: But by distribution don't we mean pdf

Comment: @user30438 Nope: many distributions do not have pdfs. A distribution of a random variable $X$ is *defined* to be its CDF.

Comment: @whuber Now I'm curious: What would be an example of a distribution that has no PDF?

Comment: @COOL The simplest is any Bernoulli distribution: it is singular with respect to Lebesgue measure, whence it has no PDF.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I think I got it. Am I right in concluding that no discrete distribution has a PDF then?

Comment: @COOL That's correct.